# Will TCP connection quanlity deteriorate as time passes?

Tags: tcp, websocket

I need to write a receiver that receives market data feed via websocket. One of my colleague said that we need to reset the connection every one hour because TCP data is buffered. I don't quite understand. Is it true that TCP connection quanlity will deteriorate as time passes?

Comment: Ask your colleague to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One of my colleague said that we need to reset the connection every one hour because TCP data is buffered.

Your colleague is mistaken.  Yes, TCP data is buffered, which is perfectly fine under normal conditions.  TCP has flow control, so if the receiver isn't reading the data correctly, or is not reading the data fast enough, the buffer could fill up over time and block the sender until buffer space is cleared.  That would be a problem with the way the receiver is coded, not a problem with TCP itself.

> Is it true that TCP connection quality will deteriorate as time passes?

Absolutely not.  Given a stable network, and proper coding management, a TCP connection can happily stay alive for days, weeks, even years without problem.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't just false, it's complete hogwash.

Network connections do not "degrade."  If you are ever seeing degradation, something between the two endpoints is having problems or the application is poorly written.

I have seen many cases were network protocols (TCP/IP, for instance) are blamed for memory leaks and other bad programming issues.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true that TCP connection quality will deteriorate as time passes?

This is false.